# How is the kafka offset value computed?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Is kafka offeset value unique per partition or per topic (considering same group id)?

Answer (score 1):

It is unique per partition. start from zero and long data type.

Answer (score 0):

It is a signed long, unique per partition and is incremented for every messages added to the partition log.