# How is Apache Kafka offset generated?

Tags: apache-kafka

Went through 
[How is the kafka offset value computed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40094936/how-is-the-kafka-offset-value-computed)

From the [kafka documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Kafka+Replication) on replication:

> The purpose of adding replication in Kafka is for stronger durability and higher availability. We want to guarantee that any successfully published message will not be lost and can be consumed, even when there are server failures. Such failures can be caused by machine error, program error, or more commonly, software upgrades.

From the [kafka documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/) on Efficiency:

> The message log maintained by the broker is itself just a directory of files, each populated by a sequence of message sets that have been written to disk in the same format used by the producer and consumer. Maintaining this common format allows optimization of the most important operation: network transfer of persistent log chunks.

I did not see anywhere details regarding how the offset is generated for a topic. Will be offsets be generated by a single machine in the cluster in which case there is one master or Kafka has distributed logging that relies on some kind of clock synchronization and generates messages in a consistent order among all the nodes.

Any pointers or additional information will be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Offsets are not generated explicitly for each message and messages do also no store their offset.

A topic consists of partitions, and messages are written to partitions in junks, called *segments* (on the file system, there will be a folder for a topic, with subfolders for each partition -- a segment corresponds to a file within a partitions folder).

Furthermore, a index is maintained per partitions and stored along with the segment files, that uses the offset of the first message per segment as key and point to the segment. For all consecutive messages within a segment, the offset of a message can be computed by it's logical position within the segment (including the offset of the first messages).

If you start a new topic or actually a new partition, a first segment is generated and its start offset zero is inserted into the index. Message get written to the segment until it's full. A new segment is started and it's start offset get's added to the index -- the start offset of the new segment can easily be computed by the start offset of the latest segment plus the number of message within this segment.

Thus, for each partitions, the broker that hosts this partitions (ie, the leader for this partition) tracks the offset for this partitions by maintaining the index. If segments are deleted because retention time passed, the segment file get's deleted and the entry in the index is removed.

Comment: Can you elaborate this with a single topic and default partition example when I do not specify any partitioning at all. I am a newbie, hence having difficulty picturing this.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question. Does this help: https://www.confluent.io/blog/hands-free-kafka-replication-a-lesson-in-operational-simplicity/